# Excel VBA filtering on Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

I get run-time error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method

I have been playing with the With statement, using activesheet.
The xDate shows the right date and I have that visible as True.

```
Sub PivotFilter()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim xDay As String
Dim xDate As Date

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Previous Day Open Pos")

xDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Previous Day Open POs").pivottables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("PO Creation Date"). _
        CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ws.pivottables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("PO Creation Date").PivotItem(xDate).Visible = True




xDay = format(Date, "dddd")

If xDay = "Monday" Then
    xDate = Date - 3
Else
    xDate = Date - 1
End If


End With


End Sub
```

I want the pivot table to click on the previous business date.

Answer (score 0):

A "With" statement is to specify an object, not to perform a setting change, as you have it.  Also, you probably need to change your xDate switching logic before you use it.

```
Sub PivotFilter()

  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim xDay As String
  Dim xDate As Date

  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Previous Day Open Pos")

  xDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)

  xDay = format(Date, "dddd")

  If xDay = "Monday" Then
     xDate = Date - 3
  Else
     xDate = Date - 1
  End If

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Previous Day Open POs").pivottables("PivotTable1") _ 
        .PivotFields("PO Creation Date").CurrentPage = "(All)"
  ws.pivottables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("PO Creation Date") _
        .PivotItem(xDate).Visible = True


End Sub
```

** Responding to comment **

That code specifies a hard coded date that will be deselected while also selecting the date you want.  This is complicated by the fact that a pivot table can't have NOTHING selected, so you need to first select then date you want, then loop through all available pivot table values and deselect those other values, skipping over your chosen date.

This is a little on the challenging side for beginner coding, imo, so if you figure this out you will learn a lot.

Comment: before writing the code, I recorded a macro and here's the code-  ActiveSheet.pivottables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("PO Creation Date"). _
        CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.pivottables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("PO Creation Date")
        .PivotItems("1/31/2019").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("1/30/2019").Visible = False
    End With

Comment: I will try to do what you suggest, by deselecting and then selecting.  This might be a little bit over my head, but I will try. thanks.

Comment: That's not going to work, you need to select and then deselect.  Attempting to deselect all with throw an error.